# My laptop is getting very hot during use

Tags: 12.04, overheating

My laptop is an Asus A46CM with Intel CPU and Nvidia Graphics. When I use Ubuntu my system runs very hot and I am unable to install the Nvidia proprietary drivers. In about 15 minutes my laptop will freeze due to the heat. I've tried other distros but they all seem to do the same thing. Can Ubuntu help with this? If so, how?

Comment: Are you using any of the thermal management programs?  I use `tlp` which you can install in 15.10 with `sudo apt-get install --install-suggests tlp`  You should also consider cleaning the fans in your laptop and making sure that they work.

Comment: umm btw i'm using 12.04 because use 15.10 only 10 min to make my laptop hang plus Internt provider in m,y country very slow i think idon't do much in 15.10 so i downgrade it to 12.04.

does your advice can work in 12.04?

Comment: You can run tlp on 12.04, but you need to load from the PPA at [https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/ubuntu/tlp](https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/ubuntu/tlp)

Comment: i'm very sorry i'm very noob in linux can you teach ppa? and how to load?

Comment: Apart from Thermald and TLP, make sure your video card drivers are installed. Most likely your heating issues are coming from nvidia card thats permanently on. For the nvidia card, the driver would allow you to turn the card on and off from the nvidia settings applet.

Comment: TLP installation from PPA: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation (or see answer below)

Answer (score 3):

Thermald has been shipped with Ubuntu since Trusty and may help resolve your issue.

sudo apt-get install thermald

The default mode should work fine, however, for some machines one may need to tweak the configuration file.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Comment: can it work on 12.04?

Comment: it should work OK,  there may be a few kernel interfaces lacking to do full thermal control, but I suggest give it a try and see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

To install TLP, open a terminal window (press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and enter the following commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp --install suggests
sudo tlp start
sudo reboot
```

Tlp as configured by default should help, however @ArupRoyChowdhury is correct that ensuring you have a valid video driver will have a great effect.  I do not use Nvidia myself, and suggest you post a seperate question about how to install the correct driver for your system

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247033/why-is-my-laptop-running-so-hot-with-ubuntu?rq=1) is a duplicate but, given the vendor, it may be.