# Asus ROG Zephyrus on Ubuntu 22.04 gets hotter than on Window 11

Tags: 22.04, asus, nvidia-optimus

I bought an Asus ROG Zephyrus m16. In Windows 11 it maintains a temperature between 35° and 45° while in Ubuntu 22.04 it maintains a temperature between 45° and 60°. Why does this happen?
How can I improve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my laptop running so hot with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247033/why-is-my-laptop-running-so-hot-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with my legion 5 (core i7 12700h & nvidia 3060m), my avg idle windows 11 temperature is ~30, and after using linux, the idle is 40-45
there's 2 thing that I do to make the temp back normal

```
Step 1: Add PPA GPU Drivers Repository to the System
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

Step 2: Identify GPU Model and Available Drivers
ubuntu-drivers devices

Step 3: Install Nvidia Driver
sudo apt install [driver_name]
for example in my case nvidia-550
```

or the simple way if you don't use Nvidia on linux, you can switch the graphics mode to use iGPU only mode, so I do this on windows 11, on Lenovo vantage, then I restart and switch to ubuntu, and you don't need to repeat this step after turn off the laptop, unless you switch the graphic mode to use Hybrid auto mode on windows